# C# asp.net core file location when running on azure AKS

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, azure-aks

I have an application that reads a .json file to configure some things.

We haveing a weird situation at the moment, our code runs perfectly fine as a console app on any of our pcs, it runs fine as we web worker on azure app service..  However if we publish this code to run on an Azure Kubernetes Cluster,  we get an exception saying that the file is not found.

When publishing our image to ACR we use the following mode;
[image]

Does the file system maybe work differently in AKS?

What am I missing here?

Example code:

```
 var DirectoryPath = @"Services\SubFolder1\Subfolder2\";
 var ConfigFileName = @"MyConfigFile.json";
 var filePath = Path.Combine(DirectoryPath, ConfigFileName);
 // Our own helper function to handle the different ways that files are stored.
 var fileInfo = StorageService.GetFileInfoFromPath(filePath);
 //If no file throw exception
 if (!fileInfo.Exists)
    {
      // When we run in AKS this line throws an exception
      throw new FileNotFoundException($"Config '{ConfigFileName}' not found.");
    }

// Our service layer which we use to find a file based on the different places it gets stored. 
public static FileInfo GetFileInfoFromPath(string path)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

        try
        {
            fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }

        
        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            try
            {
                fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, path));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }
        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            try
            {
                fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(global::System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location ?? string.Empty, path));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        return fileInfo;
    }
```

I checked on the actual file is set to always copy to the output directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a publish :
Assembly.Location Property is empty
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-5.0#remarks

> In .NET 5 and later versions, for bundled assemblies, the value returned is an empty string.

Issue closed : https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/20939

In this case it's better to always use :

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```